# category product collection from the current category to parent category

Tags: magento2

I would like to change the category product collection from the current category to the parent category?

I have created a custom category in which I would like to load the collection of the parent category

Comment: in-spite of $category->getProductCollection() try $category->getParentCategory()->getProductCollection();

Comment: Which file should I make change?

Comment: For which page you are doing the changes?

Comment: I am working on the category page

I need to load parent category products collection instead of current category in category listing page

Comment: I think its Magento/CatalogModel/Layer/Filter/Category line no 74, $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category);

Comment: So, What i need to change?